# Get specific object in array on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have to update an object in an array when I click on the button. But I can't select the object I clicked.

there is my git for better reading https://github.com/Azciop/BernamontSteven_P7_V2

Code:

```
data() {
        return {
            post: {
                file: "",
                content: "",
            },
            showModal: false,
            showModifyPost: false,
            user: {
                firstname: "",
                lastname: "",
                _id: "",
            },

        };
    },
```

this is the get function

```
getAllPost() {
            axios
                .get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("getPosts", response.data);
                    this.post = response.data;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
```

this is the update post function

```
updatePost(id) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", this.post[1].file);
            formData.append("content", this.post[1].content);
            axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post/' + id, formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    location.reload("/accueil");
                }).catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                )
        },
```

and this is the html with the v-for to display and the modify part

```
<div class="post" :key="post._id" v-for="post in post">
                <!-- update a post -->
                <button @click="showModifyPost = true" v-if="post.userId == user._id  || user.isAdmin == true"
                    class="button button-modify-post">Modifier</button>
                <transition name="fade" appear>
                    <div class="modal-overlay" v-if="showModifyPost" @click="showModifyPost = false"></div>
                </transition>
                <transition name="slide" appear>
                    <div class="modifiyPostModal" v-if="showModifyPost">
                        <span>
                            <h2 class="center-text">Modifier votre publication</h2>
                            <div class="close-post_button" @click="showModifyPost = false">
                                <font-awesome-icon class="close_create_post" icon="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark" />
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div>
                                <input class="textPost" name="createPost" placeholder="Quoi de neuf ?"
                                    v-model="post.content" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="center-sendbutton">
                                <input type="file" class="publishPost" id="changePicture" v-on:change="selectFile" ref="file" />
                                <button type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="updatePost(post._id)" class="publishPost">Modifier</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </transition>
```

This is the create Function

```
selectFile() {
            this.posts.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
        },
        // create post 
        async submitCreatePost() {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', this.posts.file);
            formData.append('content', this.posts.content);
            formData.append('firstname', localStorage.getItem("firstname"));
            formData.append('lastname', localStorage.getItem("lastname"));
            formData.append('userId', localStorage.getItem("userId"));
            await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post",
                formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    }
                }).then(
                    console.log(formData),
                    this.content = "",
                    this.file = "",
                ).then((response) => response.status >= 200 || response.status <= 201 ? 
                 location.reload(true) : console.log(response.statusText))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        },
```

but when i update it, it does update the object 1 (because it's the one selected in the js function)

i'd like to know how can i do to select the object i clicked. Thanks

Comment: can you tell from which array you want to select, as from the code no array seems to be present

Comment: yes, so i have an array called getPosts with currently 3 posts inside. inside each of the posts i have multipe values such as _id (its the post id), userId, firstname, lastname, etc.

Comment: and i want to modify the content and the imageUrl(file) in the index 1. this is the picture of the console.log of getPosts https://gyazo.com/50b1c09b569de148aa31e630738449a1

Comment: you can use filter or find function, if you want to get the exact object from the array with a particular key

Comment: i tried this var post = post.find(post => post._id === this.post._id); but i get the errow message Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Comment: this.post is an empty post object present in your current vue component. You have to have the array in the current component. The find or filter works only on arrays. where is the getPosts defined ? is it a vuex getter?

Comment: i did an axios.get to get all my posts .get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post')
    .then((response) => {
     console.log("getPosts", response.data);
     this.post = response.data;
    }).catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
    })

Comment: i just realiste that the array might be call post or posts. and not getPosts as it is just a console.log

Comment: and where are you calling this api call? is it in created lifecycle hook ?
If post is an array then define it as array in the data option. If you put the script block of the vue component, I can help

Comment: ok, i am not sure i understand what you exactly asked as i am new to coding, ill make an answer with more code so its better to read than in just a simple comment !

Comment: sure, please go through the vue lifecycle hooks concept, it will be required later.

Comment: ill check that thank!! i also updated my original post !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way to do it, don't know if it the right way but it works so...

when i click on the modify button i store the current post's id in the local storage and then i do this.

```js
updatePost() {
            const thisPostId = localStorage.getItem("ThisPostId")
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", this.post.file);
            formData.append("content", this.post.content);
            axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post/' + thisPostId, formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    },
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.posts = response.data;
                    this.getAllPost();
                    this.showModifyPost = false
                }).catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                )
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
export default {
created(){
    this.getAllPost()
},
data(){
    return{
        posts: [],
        post: {
            file: "",
            content: "",
        },
        showModal: false,
        showModifyPost: false,
        user: {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            _id: "",
        },
    }
},
methods:{
    getAllPost() {
        axios
            .get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("getPosts", response.data);
                this.posts = response.data;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    },
    updatePost(id) {
        //the find part
        const postToBeFound=this.posts.find((post)=>post._id===id)
        console.log(postToBeFound)
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", postToBeFound.file);
        formData.append("content", postToBeFound.content);
        axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post/' + id, formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                location.reload("/accueil");
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            }
            )
    }
}
```

}

Error is happening at

```
formData.append("image", this.post[1].file);
 formData.append("content", this.post[1].content);
```

since post is an object post[1] will give error. In my original answer also I made the fix

```
formData.append("image", postToBeFound.file);
formData.append("content", postToBeFound.content);
```

Comment: thanks,i tried. but the i get this error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1') and also this [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler

Comment: i will also show my createPost to let you see how i get the image file

Comment: That means from api no object is coming with same id, in console.log(postToBeFound) what was the result?

Comment: it does show the new content

Comment: it also display the correct postId and userId

Comment: I hope in the html part, in v-for you fixed post in posts. and can you tell for which line you are getting the error then? it will be present in the browser console

Comment: yes i changed it.  at Proxy.updatePost (Accueil.vue?e918:220:1)
    at eval (Accueil.vue?e918:67:1)
    at eval (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?2725:1481:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:155:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:164:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?2725:369:1)

Comment: sorry, but you have to share the full script block. it is very difficult to figure out  where error is happening, as most of the api calls are having catch block. I hope in the backend you have the put call declared. for better debugging you can check the network tab in browser devtools, see if any problem wrt api call

Comment: may i send you the git?

Comment: sure...post it in the question

Comment: Done! thank you so much for the time you put in my problem !!!!

Comment: Please remove/change the api keys in the .env file and add env file and node_modules in gitignore. Use this as reference https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files. Also I updated the answer

Comment: thank you so much. i changed the data and the updatePost But i still have an error after the change ! it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file'). and when i select an image i have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0').

Comment: can you try the updated answer, by mistake I kept this.postToBeFound.file whereas it should be like the following
formData.append("image", postToBeFound.file);
formData.append("content", postToBeFound.content);

Comment: i tried to change the content without modifying the image. it changed the content but it deleted the image. also, if i try to change the image, it says runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:218 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). and also. if i try to modify the post [0]. It modify the latest post created and not the post i selected

Comment: my bad it doenst delete the image if i change the content. but i still cant change the image and it change the content of the wrong post

Comment: Please try the console.log the found post and use its image and content for the api call. if it works then you can try different things and send the api call as per your usecase. let me know if you face any more error

Comment: the problem i face is just that when i modify the content, it always target the higher index post. and when i chose a new file it get the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: so i think i have an issue on the formData.append("content", postToBeFound.content); and also on the selectFile() {
   this.posts.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
  },

Comment: because the console log does show the new content. but it doesnt show the new imageUrl